# What is the difference between svg's x and dx attribute?

Tags: svg, d3.js

What is the difference between svg's x and dx attribute (or y and dy)? When would be a proper time to use the axis shift attribute (dx) versus the location attribute (x)?

For example, I have noticed a lot of d3 examples doing something like this

```
chart.append("text")
   .attr("x", 0)
   .attr("y", 0)
   .attr("dy", -3)
   .text("I am a label")
```

What is the advantage or reasoning for setting both y and dy when the following seems to do the same thing?

```
chart.append("text")
   .attr("x", 0)
   .attr("y", -3)
   .text("I am a label")
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`x` and `y` are absolute coordinates and `dx` and `dy` are relative coordinates (relative to the specified `x` and `y`).

In my experience, it is not common to use `dx` and `dy` on `<text>` elements (although it might be useful for coding convenience if you, for example, have some code for positioning text and then separate code for adjusting it).

`dx` and `dy` are mostly useful when using `<tspan>` elements nested inside a `<text>` element to establish fancier multi-line text layouts.

For more details you can check out the [Text section of the SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html).

Comment: It seems to me that in `d3.js`, it is used for combining different units. Like `x="3" dx="0.5em"` which amounts to 3 pixels + half a text line.

Answer (score 79):

To add to Scott's answer, dy used with em (font size units) is very useful for vertically aligning text relative to the absolute y coordinate. This is covered in the [MDN dy text element example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dy#text).

Using dy=0.35em can help vertically centre text regardless of font size. It also helps if you want to rotate the centre of your text around a point described by your absolute coordinates.

```
<style>
text { fill: black; text-anchor: middle; }
line { stroke-width: 1; stroke: lightgray; }
</style>


<script>
dataset = d3.range(50,500,50);

svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
svg.attr('width',500).attr('height', 500);

svg.append("line").attr('x1', 0).attr('x2', 500).attr('y1', 100).attr('y2', 100);
svg.append("line").attr('x1', 0).attr('x2', 500).attr('y1', 200).attr('y2', 200);

group = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

// Without the dy=0.35em offset
group.append("text")
    .text("My text")
    .attr("x",function (d) {return d;})
    .attr("y",100)
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {return "rotate("+45*i+","+d+",100)";});

// With the dy=0.35em offset
group.append("text")
    .text("My text")
    .attr("x",function (d) {return d;})
    .attr("y",200)
    .attr("dy","0.35em")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {return "rotate("+45*i+","+d+",200)";});
<script>
```

[View it in Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPEgoE)

If you don't include "dy=0.35em", the words rotate around the bottom of the text and after 180 align below where they were before rotation. Including "dy=0.35em" rotates them around the centre of the text.

Note that dy can't be set using CSS.

Comment: In case someone else runs into this, I couldn't get this working unless I set svg = d3.select("body").append("svg"); and then did the attr on the next line. svg.attr({width:500,height:300});. Thanks for sharing!