# How to properly arrange labels of a circle?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a circle like the following:

[image]

As you might notice, labels from 0 to 9 have different proximity to the outer circle in comparison to other labels. My expectations are:

1. How can I have same distance of a label to the outer circle?
2. How can I arrange labels so that they are in the middle of the line that comes from center, and not in the side of it?

You can find my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ao4xwpnk/

I tried to change this part of my code to have symmetry of labels, but it did not work.

```html
  let featureData = features.map((f, i) => {
    let angle = (Math.PI / 2) + (2 * Math.PI * i / features.length);
    let isLeftHalf = angle < Math.PI; // Check if the angle is in the left half of the circle

    let value = isLeftHalf ? 14.5 : 10.5; // Adjust the value for labels in left and right halves

    return {
      "name": f,
      "angle": angle,
      "line_coord": angleToCoordinate(angle, 180),
      "label_coord": angleToCoordinate(angle, value)
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`text-anchor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor) and [`dy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dy#text) attributes on the `text` element will help:

```
// draw axis label
svg.selectAll(".axislabel")
  .data(featureData)
  .join(
    enter => enter.append("text")
      .attr("x", d => d.label_coord.x)
      .attr("y", d => d.label_coord.y)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")     // <-- here
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")              // <-- and here
      .text(d => d.name)
```

`text-anchor` works for the horizontal placing:

> The rendered characters are aligned such that the middle of the text
> string is at the current text position.

Which solves the problem for you that you are trying to use `isLeftHalf` for.

The `dy` attribute works for the vertical placing. The value of `0.35em` is a convention - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19140412/765395) which interestingly says:

> Using dy=0.35em can help vertically centre text regardless of font
> size

My read on it is that this value accounts for an average of the descenders in the font design e.g. for p and g the 'tail' is roughly 35% of the height and you are therefore pushing the label 'down' by that to line it up with the axes. See [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97384/what-is-the-standard-proportion-of-a-fonts-descent) for example.

Your code with this update:

```js
let data = [];
    let features = [0, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]; // labels on the circle
    //generate the data
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var point = {}
      //each feature will be a random number from 1-9
      features.forEach(f => point[f] = 1 + Math.random() * 162);
      data.push(point);
    }

    let width = 600;
    let height = 600;
    let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    //adding radial scale
    let radialScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 180])
      .range([0, 250]);

    //adding ticks
    let ticks = [20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180]; // 9 circles

    //adding circles
    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(ticks)
      .join(
        enter => enter.append("circle")
          .attr("cx", width / 2)
          .attr("cy", height / 2)
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .attr("stroke", "gray")
          .attr("r", d => radialScale(d))
          .attr("stroke-width", 1) // Set the same stroke-width for all circles
      );

    //adding white background circle to remove filling in the center
    svg.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", width / 2)
      .attr("cy", height / 2)
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .attr("stroke", "gray")
      .attr("r", radialScale(20))
      .attr("stroke-width", 1); // Set the same stroke-width for the center circle

    //adding text labels
    svg.selectAll(".ticklabel")
      .data(ticks)
      .join(
        enter => enter.append("text")
          .attr("class", "ticklabel")
          .attr("x", width / 2 + 5)
          .attr("y", d => height / 2 - radialScale(d))
          .text(d => d.toString())
      );

    //Plotting the Axes
    //map an angle and value into SVG
    function angleToCoordinate(angle, value) {
      let x = Math.cos(angle) * radialScale(value);
      let y = Math.sin(angle) * radialScale(value);
      return { "x": width / 2 + x, "y": height / 2 - y };
    }

    let featureData = features.map((f, i) => {
      let angle = (Math.PI / 2) + (2 * Math.PI * i / features.length);
      let value = i < 9 ? 10.5 : 12; // Adjust the value for labels 13 to 21 to 12
      return {
        "name": f,
        "angle": angle,
        "line_coord": angleToCoordinate(angle, 180),
        "label_coord": angleToCoordinate(angle, 190) // changin 190 allows me to adjust labels proximity to the circle!
      };
    });

    // draw axis line
    svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(featureData)
      .join(
        enter => enter.append("line")
          .attr("x1", width / 2)
          .attr("y1", height / 2)
          .attr("x2", d => d.line_coord.x)
          .attr("y2", d => d.line_coord.y)
          .attr("stroke", "black")
          .attr("stroke-width", 1) // Set the same stroke-width for all axis lines
      );

    // draw axis label
    svg.selectAll(".axislabel")
      .data(featureData)
      .join(
        enter => enter.append("text")
          .attr("x", d => d.label_coord.x)
          .attr("y", d => d.label_coord.y)
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("dy", "0.35em")
          .text(d => d.name)
      );

    //draw shapes for actual data
    let line = d3.line()
      .x(d => d.x)
      .y(d => d.y);

    let area = d3.area()
      .x(d => d.x)
      .y0(d => d.y)
      .y1(height / 2)
      .curve(d3.curveLinear);

    let colors = ["red", "green", "navy"];

    //helper function to iterate through fields in each data point
    function getPathCoordinates(data_point) {
      let coordinates = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        let ft_name = features[i];
        let angle = (Math.PI / 2) + (2 * Math.PI * i / features.length);
        coordinates.push({
          x: width / 2 + Math.cos(angle) * radialScale(data_point[ft_name]),
          y: height / 2 - Math.sin(angle) * radialScale(data_point[ft_name])
        });
      }
      return coordinates;
    }

    // Modify the path elements to separate red and green data
    svg.selectAll(".path-red")
      .data([data[0]]) // Data for the red line
      .join(
        enter => enter.append("path")
          .datum(d => getPathCoordinates(d))
          .attr("class", "path-red")
          .attr("d", line)
          .attr("stroke-width", 3)
          .attr("stroke", "red")
          .attr("fill", "none") // No fill for the red line
      );

    svg.selectAll(".path-green")
      .data([data[1]]) // Data for the green line
      .join(
        enter => enter.append("path")
          .datum(d => getPathCoordinates(d))
          .attr("class", "path-green")
          .attr("d", line)
          .attr("stroke-width", 3)
          .attr("stroke", "green")
          .attr("fill", "none") // No fill for the green line
      );

    // Fill the area between the red and green lines
    let areaFillData = [
      ...getPathCoordinates(data[0]),
      ...getPathCoordinates(data[1]).reverse()
    ];

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(areaFillData)
      .attr("d", area)
      .attr("stroke-width", 0)
      .attr("fill", "blue") // Fill the area between the red and green lines with blue color
      .attr("fill-opacity", 0.3); // You can adjust the opacity as you like
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```